# How to display google chart in my View?

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I create an array in c# in my controller which looks like that :

```
[["test", "atest", "btest", "ctest"],["1","2","3","4"]...]
```

So it's an array of arrays. Then I pass it to the View in ViewBag named **ViewBag.TabComplet**.
Now I need to pass that array of datas to the google chart vizualisation as follows :

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"], callback: drawVisualization() });
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(@ViewBag.TabComplet);
    var options = {
        title: "Nombres d'incidents ouverts en Hotline en 2013",
        vAxis: { title: "Cups" },
        hAxis: { title: "Month" },
        seriesType: "bars",
        series: { 2: { type: "line"} },
        colors: ["blue", "#01A9DB", "red"]
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

But unfortunalty it shows me an error saying: **Unexpected Token ]**
Does somebody have a solution ?

Comment: can you post your full array

Comment: What is your fist line? Is it data or? What are you trying to represent... give us some info.

Comment: Open the page in a browser, view the source, and post the javascript so we can see what that code is producing.

Comment: I've found the solution and answered at my question below. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. For those interested, the javascript function **arrayToDataTable**
analyzes the type of datas in each column and if a data that you want to display is not an int, a error is displayed and shows that the data is not of a right type. If you want to avoid using that function, you can use the different functions **addRow**, **addColumn**,.. to hardly build a right array of datas.
According to that, I've created a function in my controller, called by an ajax call and which returns me a JSON array which looks like that:

```
[["Mois","Nombre incidents","Nombre incidents pris en direct"],["Jan",15,2],["Fév",9,5],["Mar",14,3],["Avr",19,9],["Mai",9,8],["Juin",12,6],["Juil",13,5],["Aoû",4,3],["Sept",11,0],["Oct",0,0],["Nov",0,0],["Dec",0,0]]
```

As you can see, it's an array of arrays where the first array is the labels of each following data and then the first value of each array is a string and will be the label of the Xaxis of each array of datas.

You can pass directly the JSON as a source of the charts. You don't need to parse it into a javascript array.